# How to consume wsdl webservice through node js

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, wsdl, strong-soap

I am using strong-soap node module i want to make call to webservice, I have wsdl file.

```
var soap = require('strong-soap').soap;
var WSDL = soap.WSDL;
var path = require('path');
var options = {};
WSDL.open('./wsdls/RateService_v22.wsdl',options,
  function(err, wsdl) {
    // You should be able to get to any information of this WSDL from this object. Traverse
    // the WSDL tree to get  bindings, operations, services, portTypes, messages,
    // parts, and XSD elements/Attributes.

    var service = wsdl.definitions.services['RateService'];
    //console.log(service.Definitions.call());
    //how to Call rateService ??
});
```

Comment: any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure about how `strong-soap` works.
But, I have some implementations of `SOAP` using [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap).

Basically, the `node-soap` package uses `Promises` to keep the requests concurrent.

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://www.webservicex.net/whois.asmx?WSDL';
var args = {name: 'value'};
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    client.GetWhoIS(args, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: I am using same but i get below error msg "TypeError: Cannot read property 'GetWhoIS' of undefined"

Answer (score 3):

Lets use the following [sample SOAP service](http://webservicex.net/New/Home/ServiceDetail/52):

> Get domain name registration record by Host Name / Domain Name (WhoIS)

To judge from your code you'd like to use a **.wsdl** file available locally, so saving it:

```
mkdir wsdl && curl 'http://www.webservicex.net/whois.asmx?WSDL' > wsdl/whois.wsdl
```

Now lets use the following code to query it:

```
'use strict';

var soap = require('strong-soap').soap;
var url = './wsdl/whois.wsdl';

var requestArgs = {
    HostName: 'webservicex.net'
};

var options = {};
soap.createClient(url, options, function(err, client) {
  var method = client['GetWhoIS'];
  method(requestArgs, function(err, result, envelope, soapHeader) {
    //response envelope
    console.log('Response Envelope: \n' + envelope);
    //'result' is the response body
    console.log('Result: \n' + JSON.stringify(result));
  });
});
```

It would produce some meaningful results.
`WSDL.open` you're trying to use is [meant for](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-soap#wsdl) working with WSDL structure

> Loads WSDL into a tree form. Traverse through WSDL tree to get to
>   bindings, services, ports, operations, and so on.

You don't necessarily need it to call a service